# Jquery changing divs based on a button click with multiple buttons

Tags: jquery, html

I have a foreach loop where for every job I print out a yes and no button.  What I am trying to figure out is when the user clicks on yes change the div in that selected job.  What I have figured out is how to change the div for all the jobs when yes is clicked.  What should I do to only change the one job?  Here is my HTML

```
<div class = "interviewed-yes-no">
       <div>
           <input class="interview-yes" type="submit" value="Yes" style="background:none!important;color:#2AACEA;
                            border:none; padding:0!important;">
           <input type="submit" value="No" style="background:none!important;color:#2AACEA;
                            border:none; padding:0!important;font: inherit;padding-right: 10% !important;">
    </div>
 </div>
<div class ="date-of-interview" style="display: none;">
        <input id="interview-date" name="interview-date" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" type="bs-date" class="form-control" value="">
</div>
```

Here is my jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".interview-yes").click(function () {
            $('.interviewed-yes-no').hide();
            $('.date-of-interview').show();
        })
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't use general selector. Instead use **.parent()** and **.find()** to select only the element related to that quiz. for example:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".interview-yes").click(function () {
            $(this).parent().parent().find('.interviewed-yes-no').hide();
            $(this).parent().parent().find('.date-of-interview').show();
        })
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="question">
<div class = "interviewed-yes-no">
           <input class="interview-yes" type="submit" value="Yes" style="background:none!important;color:#2AACEA;
                            border:none; padding:0!important;">
           <input type="submit" value="No" style="background:none!important;color:#2AACEA;
                            border:none; padding:0!important;font: inherit;padding-right: 10% !important;">
 </div>
<div class ="date-of-interview" style="display: none;">
        <input id="interview-date" name="interview-date" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" type="bs-date" class="form-control" value="">
</div>
</div>
<div class="question">
<div class = "interviewed-yes-no">
           <input class="interview-yes" type="submit" value="Yes" style="background:none!important;color:#2AACEA;
                            border:none; padding:0!important;">
           <input type="submit" value="No" style="background:none!important;color:#2AACEA;
                            border:none; padding:0!important;font: inherit;padding-right: 10% !important;">
 </div>
<div class ="date-of-interview" style="display: none;">
        <input id="interview-date" name="interview-date" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" type="bs-date" class="form-control" value="">
</div>
</div>
```